# C++ Avoiding or managing a circular project dependency in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, project, projects-and-solutions

I am working on making my application be implemented using more of a plugin system.

This results in me having my main application EXE (or DLL, but I don't think it needs to be), which exports all the symbols for the core functionality.

I then have plugin DLL's that only need to export a simple `IPlugin* createPlugin();` so the plugin can be dynamically loaded at run time, and link against the main application for utility and class methods (I do not plan to wrap them all in virtual interfaces to work via the IPlugin, and at any rate there are things that really benefit from inlining).

Getting this correctly built is simple enough, build the app to get the import lib, then build the plugins.

however the problem I would like to solve is the simple one that if I am in the MSVC IDE and have the app as the start up project, and run it ("Start [Without] Debugging") I want to ensure that any plugin projects get fully built first (just to avoid dev mistakes that end up with old code being run).

Comment: IIRC you right-click Solution and go into the Project Depencies window. There is a list that shows all the projects in the solution and allows you to specify which projects depend on what.

Comment: Your title is totally misleading. There is no circular dependency in your problem description.

Comment: @Qix Of course this is the basic solution, but if you tried that you would know that MSVC specifically disallows a circular project dependency. @D Drmmr There is in the IDE project case if just running and not pressing the build solution button, if you have a better title feel free to edit/suggest it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the startup project to a pseudo-project that depends on all the others, and has its "executable to be debugged" in the project configuration set to the output of the main application.

Comment: This sounds like a good work around. I did consider making a launcher app, but I think this is better at least until I have a purpose for a launcher exe.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> (uncheck) Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run.

Comment: Will try in the morning.